# What is the purpose of local class field theory? What is the correspondence?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

"We have a correspondence between the abelian extensions of local fields and the multiplicative structure of the field." I am not sure if this sentence is true or not.

Does local class field theory give us more than this correspondence, which I do not notice? How the multiplicative structure is related to the abelian extensions? Is it something related to finite indexed subgroups of $K^{\star}$?

Comment: The “main theorem” (*Artin’s theorem*, I think) of local class field theory is the existence (for eg finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) of a “natural” bijection with $K^{\times}/N(L^{\times}) \rightarrow Gal(L/K)^{ab}$ for a finite Galois extension $L/K$ of finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. It is completed by the *existence theorem* which says that each finite index subgroup of $K^{\times}$ is the group of norms of some (unique? I’m not sure any more) finite abelian extension $L/K$.

Comment: Did you try to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_class_field_theory ? I quote: "The existence theorem in local class field theory establishes a one-to-one correspondence between open subgroups of finite index in the multiplicative group $K^\times$ and finite abelian extensions of the field $K$. For a finite abelian extension $L$ of $K$ the corresponding open subgroup of finite index is the norm group $N(L^\times)$."

Comment: I *think* that under some additional assumptions on $L/K$ (unramified and maybe something more?), the image of a Frobenius element is a uniformizer. That’s how this bijection relates to arithmetic. Local class field theory is usually necessary to develop *global* class field theory which has resembling (but more involved, involving ideles for instance) statements.

Comment: @CaptainLama Can we say something more specific? For example I know that the quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are in bijection with index $2$ subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\star}$. Can we say that any abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $n$ corresponds to a subgroup of index $n$? Is it true?

Comment: @Mindlack Can we say that any abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $n$ corresponds to a subgroup of index $n$?

Comment: Yes, if you look at Mindlack's comment, or the wp link, you can see that $K^\times/N(L^\times)$ is isomorphic to the Galois group of $L/K$, so the index of the norm group is the degree of the corresponding extension.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks for your kind answers.